# Where does this famous St. Augustine quote about the repentant thief come from?

Tags: reference-request, augustine

There is a very famous quote in French Catholic circles that would be translated as something like:

> No, I had not studied the Scriptures, but Jesus looked at me on the
>   cross and, in his gaze, I understood everything!

Most pages in French don't give the reference and the little bit of Latin that I know has not been very helpful in search the [complete works of Augustine in Latin](https://www.augustinus.it/latino/index.htm). Does anyone have an idea of where this quote might come from? Thanks and God bless!

Comment: Welcome!  I'd love to be able to answer this, but won't have time.  So I'll point you to what I've found so far, a quote on [catholicism.org](https://catholicism.org/the-good-thief.html): "S. Cyril teaches the same as S. Leo (Cat. Lect. xiii.) saying, “What virtue illuminated thee, 0 thief? Who taught thee to love contempt, and that, when thou wast affixed to the cross? 0 light undying, lighting the darkness!” S. Augustine follows out at length the same idea (Serm. xiii. de Temp.)"  Looks like that "Serm. xiii. de Temp." might be the answer – just haven't found the full text yet.

Comment: Are you referring to [Jean Lafrance's quote in _Demeurer en Dieu_](https://books.google.com/books?id=ggj4rv5GOXgC&pg=PA148)?

Comment: @Nathaniel That appears to be excerpted from [Cornelius à Lapide's commentary on Lk. 23:42](https://archive.org/details/cu31924092350606/page/n511), which has more St. Augustine quotes on the following pages (pp. 495 ff.).

Comment: @Geremia Not in particular, no. My professor of Sacred Scripture cites this passage often but has never found the reference and he would like it. I also appears in _Le courage d'avoir peur_ by Fr. Molinié.

Comment: It's quoted on the fourth page of [this document](https://www.nd-chretiente.com/dossiers/pdf/articles/2004_le%20bon%20larron_abbaye%20nd%20de%20fongombault.pdf) ending with "En fait, le texte n’est pas de Saint Augustin"

Comment: I heard this comment attributed to St Augustine, on the good thief : "He (the good thief) stole throughout his life and ultimately, stole the Kingdom of Heaven ". Unfortunately, I am unable to quote the source.

Comment: @Geremia That document does not contain the quotation that the OP is referencing. The

Answer (score 1):

According to ***Augustine: A New Biography* by James J. O'Donnell**,

> Samuel Beckett tormented his interpreters with a story he told one time, supposedly to help them understand *Waiting for Godot*. He used to read, he said, a lot of Augustine in the Bibliothèque Nationale in Paris and recalled one passage in particular: "Do not despair," he remembered Augustine saying, "one of the thieves was saved. Do not presume, one of the thieves was damned." Thinking of Vladimir and Estragon as the two thieves crucified with Jesus is intriguing, to say the least, and is wonderfully Beckett-like that the particular passage cannot be found anywhere in the surviving writings of Augustine or anywhere in the pages of *Patrologia Latina*, for all that language and tenor are quite perfectly Augustinian. Did Beckett make up the quotation? Is he the most modern of pseudo-Augustines?

When searching around, the quotation is usually appended to Augustine and it is through Beckett that it all started, though it is a growing consensus in academia that it was not Augustine that penned the phrase but Beckett.